# How to import tweets with only the hashtag?

Tags: ruby, json, twitter, hashtag

I'm looking to write a script to import tweets by only grabbing tweets with the designated hashtag. And I'm a little confused on how I would go about doing that. Ideally I would like just the raw data. Nothing fancy.

I tried working with tweetstream in Ruby but I see the majority of Twitter API is in JSON, which I'm not too familiar with. Anyways, does anyone have an idea of how I can simply import tweets based on a hashtag? Maybe stream it in my terminal?

Comment: using Ruby does not stop you from using JSON. It looks like you need to refresh your understanding of how JSON is used and why it cannot be compared to a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the foundation of many web APIs. I think the general consensus would be...

[Learn JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

It really is not that hard of a notation. Here is a [tutorial specifically on JSON in Ruby](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_ruby_example.htm).

Example:

```
require 'json'

json_result = "{'tweet': '#awesomesauce is for the #winner'}" # From Twitter API
results = JSON.parse(json_result)
# => {:tweet => "#awesomesauce is for the #winner"}
```